# the relationship of the primary keys in the two tables to another table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

my tables

```
A_ID   NAME
1     apple
2     banana
3     watermelon
4     kiwi
5     peace

B_ID   NAME 
1     green
2     red
3     blue
4     yellow
```

relationship table;

```
A_ID | B_ID
1      2
1      3
2      4
3      1
```

I want to print at Php;

- apple-red
- apple-blue

Comment: That's a simple inner join between those 3 tables, something like `SELECT a.name, b.name FROM a JOIN a_b ON a.id=a_b.a_id JOIN b ON b.id=a_b.b_id` what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Join Query you can done it .

```
SELECT A.name, B.name FROM A JOIN AB ON A.id=AB.A_id JOIN B ON B.id=AB.B_id
```